# Getting Element (not Node) below root in Java DOM (XML parser)

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

I need to get the tag of an element right below the root, but DOM seems only to offer methods getting child nodes (not elements) and you cant cast from one to the other.

http://ideone.com/SUjRmn

```
@Override
public void loadXml(String filepath) throws Exception {
    File f = new File(filepath);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = null;
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        doc = db.parse(f);
    } catch (SAXException | IOException | NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

    Node firstChild = root.getFirstChild();
    String tag = firstChild.getNodeName();

    //here is the problem. I can't cast from Node to Element and Node
    //stores only an int value, not the name of the object I want to restore

    ShapeDrawer drawable = null;
    switch (tag) {
        case "scribble":
            drawable = new ScribbleDrawer();
    ...
```

From the class to restore:

```
@Override
public void setValues(Element root) {
    NodeList nodelist = null;

    nodelist = root.getElementsByTagName("color");
    colorManager.setColor((nodelist.item(0).getTextContent()));
    this.color = colorManager.getCurrentColor();
    System.out.println(color.toString());

    nodelist = root.getElementsByTagName("pressx");
    pressx = Integer.parseInt(nodelist.item(0).getTextContent());
    System.out.println(pressx);

    nodelist = root.getElementsByTagName("pressy");
    pressy = Integer.parseInt(nodelist.item(0).getTextContent());
    System.out.println(pressy);

    nodelist = root.getElementsByTagName("lastx");
    lastx = Integer.parseInt(nodelist.item(0).getTextContent());

    nodelist = root.getElementsByTagName("lasty");
    lasty = Integer.parseInt(nodelist.item(0).getTextContent());
}

public void toDOM(Document doc, Element root) {
    System.out.println("ScribbleDrawer being saved");
    Element shapeBranch = doc.createElement("scribble");
    Attr attr1 = doc.createAttribute("hashcode");
    attr1.setValue(((Integer) this.hashCode()).toString());
    shapeBranch.setAttributeNode(attr1);
    root.appendChild(shapeBranch);
    Element eColor = doc.createElement("color");
    eColor.setTextContent(colorManager.namedColorToString(color));
    shapeBranch.appendChild(eColor);

    // creating tree branch
    Element press = doc.createElement("press");

    Attr attr2 = doc.createAttribute("pressx");
    attr2.setValue(((Integer) pressy).toString());
    press.setAttributeNode(attr2);

    Attr attr3 = doc.createAttribute("pressy");
    attr3.setValue(((Integer) pressy).toString());
    press.setAttributeNode(attr3);

    shapeBranch.appendChild(press);

    Element last = doc.createElement("last");

    Attr attr4 = doc.createAttribute("lastx");
    attr4.setValue(((Integer) lastx).toString());
    last.setAttributeNode(attr4);

    Attr attr5 = doc.createAttribute("lasty");
    attr5.setValue(((Integer) lasty).toString());
    last.setAttributeNode(attr5);

    shapeBranch.appendChild(last);
}
```

I know other parsers are easier, but I am almost finished and when it comes to polymorphy JAXB seems to be just as complicated with Option-marshalling etc

EDIT: this is what the xml looks like; instead of "scribble" other tags/polymorphic children are possible which are deserialized from different instance variables (and thus different DOM-trees except for the root)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Drawables>
  <scribble hashcode="189680059">
    <color>Black</color>
    <press pressx="221" pressy="221"/>
    <last lastx="368" lasty="219"/>
  </scribble>
  <scribble hashcode="1215837841">
    <color>Black</color>
    <press pressx="246" pressy="246"/>
    <last lastx="368" lasty="221"/>
  </scribble>
```

Comment: root.getDocumentElement()?

Comment: root is already assigned to getDocumentElement(). Maybe naming it root was a little confusing.

Comment: You are right. There's nothing like `getChildren()` to return all the child elements. But you can use `getElementsByTagName()` which returns elements, or use XPath as an alternative to fetch the nodes you want.

Comment: Now I see that you linked your code. I suggest you edit your question and use the code editor to add it here. It wasn't obvious to me your code was there, and others may also not notice it. The editor formats code very nicely if you use the `{}` tool to indent it.

Comment: ok, edited; hope that helps

Comment: And since you are parsing XML, please include your XML as well since it's relevant to this problem.

Comment: If your node *is* an `Element`, you *can` cast it from node to element. But your first child may also be a text node, which can't be cast, of course. You have to test the nodes for their NodeType before casting.

Comment: You mean with a for loop? what exactly do I call inside?

Comment: getNodeType() returns a constant which you can test. I'll post an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your node is an Element, you *can* cast it from node to element. But your first child might also be a text node, which can't be cast, of course. You have to test the nodes for their `NodeType` before casting.

If your XML is not using namespaces, you can use a method like this one to extract your child elements. It receives a list of nodes, test each one and returns a list containing only the elements:

```
public static List getChildren(Element element) {
    List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    NodeList nodeList = element.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            elements.add((Element) node);
        }
    }
    return elements;
}
```

An alternative is to use an API which already includes such utility methods, like DOM4J, or JDOM.